# A question about the Project Almanac and the cameras used by the characters in the film

Tags: time-travel, project-almanac

Just watched *Project Almanac* and my question is similar to another I read on here.

I understand why there are two old camcorders at the end—the one David’s Dad used to film his birthday party and one that David leaves behind in the basement—but my main question is: At the end of the movie we are watching what the sister is filming on a third camera; most likely a phone camera. Surely the very fact that we see her filming with a third camera makes what we see next null and void?

I could understand if the footage on camera 2 (which showed what we just watched in the movie) started with them going to the basement, but it’s not. Instead it’s footage of them finding the first camcorder which she would have done with a modern camera not an old camcorder otherwise she wouldn’t be commenting on how old it is! Unless it’s possible to add mobile phone footage to a camcorder?

What I’m saying is that surely her filming them finding the camcorder proves the whole thing impossible, doesn’t it?

Comment: “Unless it’s possible to add mobile phone footage to a camcorder?” — You can output video to whatever you want, including video tapes. I mean, that’s how they got video onto video tapes in the old days.

Answer (score 2):

The film plays pretty fast and loose with this.  The camcorder you're asking about is an old one that you rest on a shoulder and hold with your hand.  It was clear that much of the 'found footage' we saw in the film was not filmed on that camcorder, it was filmed on modern cameras (i.e. smartphones, GoPros, etc).

I think we have to assume that for some reason, they took the footage recorded from the various cameras, and transferred it back to that old camcorder.  It's unclear why they'd do this (maybe they used it as an archive?), but it's the only way all the footage we see in the film would then end up back on that camcorder, as is implied at the end of the film.

However, to directly address your question, she recorded the initial video on something modern, then later it was transferred to the old camcorder.